# Paypal Express Checkout insists on phone number even though option turned off (calling from Magento)

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout, phone-number

I'm using the Paypal 'Express Checkout' option in Magento.
(I'm not using any express checkout buttons, it's just because I was having problem with returning from Website Payments Standard).

In Paypal's Website Payment Preferences, I've set the 'Contact Telephone Number' field to off.
I've also made a number of changes on the Magento side to make telephone number optional
(as per [this post](http://reinoud.net/2011/03/magento-removing-mandatory-validation-of-telephone-field/)).

However, the telephone number field still appears during Paypal checkout, and is mandatory. Obviously, this is potentially going to cause customers to abandon the transaction.

Initial response from Paypal support is that the telephone number is always mandatory, that the preference setting only controls whether or not the value is returned to the seller - this doesn't sound right to me, since it makes the setting largely useless.

Given that Magento usually requires a phone number, I'm wonder if possibly something in the Magento Paypal API  call is overriding the default setting?

There must be some way of making the phone number optional?

**Edit:**
It would appear after further contact with support, and some more digging, that despite the description of the parameter, Paypal will always insist on a contact number  for non-Paypal accounts (i.e. paying directly by credit card). This applies for Website Payments Standard and Express checkout at least, possibly more.
The 'Telephone number off' parameter then controls whether the phone number entered is returned to the store.

This strikes me as daft. If I'm on a checkout somewhere and asked to enter a phone number,I don't particularly care whether it's Paypal or the merchant asking me for it, I'm not going to be happy about it and quite possibly abort the transaction, especially if it's for a site I haven't shopped with before. I don't even see why Paypal need the number - if there's a suggestion of somebody fraudulently using my card I'd expect a call from my card company, not Paypal. I'd probably hang up if someone claiming to be from Paypal called me.

Plus given that is the way it works, they could have made it a lot clearer by pointing out the the 'Phone number off' field only applies some of the time

/rant

Comment: I couldn't agree more. PayPal are a bunch of morons.
However here is some feedback on your problem: I believe the phone number may be used for credit-card matching purposes, or fraud-detection purposes. They may also be able to use it to detect whether you have an existing PayPal account or have bought through PayPal before.
Either way, this problem still persists, a full 2 years and 4 months after your last post. The setting description is still wrong.
PayPal suck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a rant about policies of a particular web service, not programming.

Comment: My initial question was assuming I was doing something wrong and seeking a better way of using the Magento API to avoid the issue. I added further information later on to clarify that this isn't actually possible. While I admit that bit did end with a bit of a rant, I still think it's a valid topic for discussion. Though admittedly perhaps the rant could be removed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the phone number option to 'On (optional)'?

Comment: I have. This will only make it optional whether the number is shared with the merchant - it does not refer to whether entering it is optional.
Clearly this is not what the setting description says. PayPal are a bunch of morons. And yes, I mean, I'm sick of their nonsense, I've given up trying to deal with them. Their support is loathsomely bad.