# Turn off mandatory phone number on paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal

We are using express checkout on paypal and the problem is the customer can't submit his/her details without providing a phone number. I think it should be optional, no one really want to tell his/her phone number. Is there any way to turn off this option?

update: This problem occurs only when the customer wants to pay by credit, debit card without logging in their account.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7436004/103167 which is also off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about policies of a third-party web service, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to Profile in PayPal and click on My Selling Tools. Click update next to Website Payment Preferences. Scroll down to Contact Telephone Number

> When you activate this option, your customers will be asked to include
>   a Contact Telephone Number with their payment information. Learn More
>
> Note: Selecting On (Required Field) could have a negative effect on
>   buyer conversion.

If your profile view is different, let me know and I will provide the directions.

Comment: tried that one, has no effect on phone number field, when the customer wants to pay by debit or credit card that field is still mandatory

Comment: Oh yes, you are referring to them checking out without a Paypal account. PayPal requires that and there is no way to turn that off, sorry.